# Privacy Issue with Heroku App

Tags: python, heroku, flask

When I try to look up some pages, I get the following:

Your connection is not private

```
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.xxx.com (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
Back to safetyHide advanced
This server could not prove that it is www.xxx.com; its security certificate is from *.herokuapp.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Proceed to www.xxx.com (unsafe)
```

What should I do to prevent this? Somehow google has https, but I know I haven't paid for a certificate and everything runs off http, but pages are indexed in google as http(s).

Answer (score 1):

You must use the SSL Endpoint addon.

Heroku use a default *.herokuapp.com certificate. For custom domains, you must use the adon.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Comment: New Heroku applications should use [Heroku SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl)